# Change Dapper so that it maps a database null value to double.NaN

Tags: .net, sqlite, ado.net, dapper

I have a nullable double column in my SQLite database.

When reading from the database (for columns of type double) I would like to convert nulls into "double.NaN".

Currently dapper sets null values to 0, which I do not want.

What are my options?

1. Modify Dapper source code.
2. Can't use Dapper, need to write my own ADO.NET code the old fashioned way?
3. change the way that I call the cnn.Query method, to modify the way that mapping happens.

My first choice is option 1, but I need help modifying Dapper.

Comment: Does dapper not support `Nullable<double>`?

Comment: @Anthony, yes and dapper works fine with Nullable<double>, unfortunately that is not an option for me. I have a large application which uses double, and sometimes sets the value to double.NaN.

Comment: I am a bit uneasy about special casing double and float ... amending dapper is going to be the safest way for you to go, and a coalesce(null, ...) would be another option. Don't think you need to drop to ado for this

Comment: I am OK amending my local Dapper to convert any nulls to double.NaN when the target property is a Double. I can't figure out which method of Dapper to amend. Can you give me a hint as to which method to change? I have spent hours looking through Dapper. Your help Sam is immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally, I will advise against this; a null is not quite the same thing as NaN. If you really want to do this, you would have to look at `GetTypeDeserializer`. The code to do this is generated dynamically using `ILGenerator`, and is fairly complex. If you look for a line:

```
il.MarkLabel(isDbNullLabel); // incoming stack: [target][target][value]
```

this is where the code branches to if a `DbNull` is detected. What it does currently is simply pop the two values (the value and the target) from the stack, drop them on the floor, and carry on. You would need to check for `float`/`double` as a special case, apply your conversion, then assign the NaN to the member.

I repeat my claim, though, that this simply isn't a valid thing to do. A much simpler option would be:

```
public double? Value {get;set;}
```

which requires zero changes, and will work currently. If you really really want it treated as a non-nullable double, maybe:

```
private double foo = double.NaN;
public double Foo { get { return foo; } set { foo = value; } }
```

this will now default to `NaN`, and materialize correctly when there are values.