# Getting Dapper to return an empty string instead of a null string

Tags: dapper

I know it's kind of the wrong thing to do, but I'm dealing with a legacy codebase that has NULLS when it means empty strings and vice versa.

I can't immediately see how it is possible, but is it possible to get (or modifiy dapper so it will) return an empty string instead of a null string when mapping back from the database.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dapper doesn't call any setter when it sees a *null*, so options might include:

- set the default value to `""` in the constructor
- check for `null` in the accessor

So:

```
public class SomeDto
{
    public SomeDto()
    {
        Name = "";
    }
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

or:

```
public class SomeDto
{
    private string name;
    public string Name { get {return name ?? "";} set {name = value;} }
}
```

However, this only applies to *reading* values; I can't think of a *nice* way to get dapper to turn `""` into `null` when passing the dto in as the parameter object; options include:

- creating an anon-type, substituting `""` to `null` (perhaps write a `string NullIfBlank(this string s)` extension method)
- having a shim property on the type that returns `null` in place of `""`, and have your database query bind to `@NameOrNull` rather than `@Name`

Comment: @Alex don't worry about it; I think I know who and why - I think someone didn't like that I criticized an answer. Somehow, I think I'll survive!

Comment: I hope you do :P - who else would answer all the dapper questions! No seriously, the site would be even better if everyone explained their downvotes.

Comment: @Alex I agree, and I always try to when downvoting. Very occasionally (and it is a minority), that can be perceived as negative, hence how we got here. But: not to worry.

Comment: Thanks Marc, that's exactly what I had, I was just wondering if there was an easily pluggable interface for mapping base types.  I looked at the IL emitting Deserializing stuff and had visions of me debugging an issue with that in production at 1am. Loving Dapper, thanks Sam and Marc!

Comment: (to be clear, I defaulted the values to an empty string in the constructor, I incorrectly assumed that having null in the source would render a null in the target - great news that it does nothing )

Answer (score 2):

You can control this with your queries, for example:

```
    public class Data
    {
        public string Foo { get; set; }
    }

    var result = conn.Query<Data>("select Foo = coalesce(Foo, '') from MyTable");
```

So in the above example, coalesce will return an empty string when Foo is null.

Answer (score 1):

**In short:** depending how you load the data to the dapper you may get two different scenarios.

**First:** Turn up your data provider layer, for example like in this post - [How to return null from a Dapper query rather than default(T)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11720611/1437962).

**Second** way to try: you may modify your `GetTypeDeserializer` like in the following post - [Change Dapper so that it maps a database null value to double.NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9334365/1437962)

Comment: First: is not really the problem I was trying to solve. Second: I thought about that, but if you've seen the Deerialization code, it doesn't make a great deal of sense to go playing around with it, breaking all upgrade paths. Third: Thanks for the friendly advice, but if you've seen my unanswered questions, you'll understand why there aren't any accepted answers.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use a global extension method on **string** called ConvertNull() which converts any null values to an empty string. You can then call this anywhere without your code looking cluttered. If you're using this directly on an aspx page, just make sure you've imported the namespace of the extension methods and then the method will be available to you:

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    using System;

    public static class StringExtensionsClass
    {
        /// <summary>Converts null strings to empty strings</summary>
        /// <param name="s">Input string</param>
        /// <returns>Original string, or empty string if original string was null</returns>
        public static string ConvertNull(this string s)
        {
            return s ?? "";
        }
    }
}
```

Then call this on an **instance** of a string.

Usage:

`myStringInstance.ConvertNull().Replace("\r\n", "<br />");`

Comment: Would it not be shorter to just write `(myStringInstance ?? "").Replace("\r\n", "<br />");`? Your extension method requires more typing that just doing the null check inline.